# Outlook 2019 rule based on envelope-sender field

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2019

I want to detect spoofed emails by checking the envelope-sender field in the header. I tried setting a new rule "if message header includes" `envelope-sender <*@domain.com>` but a wildcard is not working.

Is it possible to filter these emails?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, we could only set specific key words in Outlook "if message header includes" rule, and a wildcard is indeed not working. Compared with "if message header includes" rule, "with specific words in the sender's address" rule might be more suitable to your requirement. For more information, please check [this similar issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/da3dd1d7-2d18-4ee6-b789-c16c5f88af9e/outlook-rule-to-allow-all-emails-from-local-domain-and-not-be-a-client-based-rule?forum=outlook).

Comment: Sender's address can be easily spoofed, so I'm trying to not rely on the From field.